# Temporarily disable all services of Firebase before user accepts consent

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have an app that has Firebase implemented. What I want is to disable everything related to Firebase before the user accepts the data collection consent. In android documentation I have seen that for example I can disable Firebase Analytics with:

```
setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
```

Okay, but what if I am using more services of Firebase?

Is there any way to disable everything related with Firebase so that any data is collected by any service of Firebase before the user has accepted the data collection consent?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for what you're trying to do.

Your best bet is to simply not initialize Firebase at all until the time is right.  An uninitialized Firebase SDK will do absolutely nothing in any of its products.  You will have to instead do manual init and not the automated init that you get from a default integration.

Comment: "Your best bet is to simply not initialize Firebase at all until the time is right" -- well, in the Firebase implementation, I have not initialized Firebase in any part of the code, I mean, I don't know how to not initialize Firebase. Also, how could I initialize Firebase manually?

Comment: By default Firebase installs itself to initialize itself.  You have to disable that and do it manually.  There are plenty of resources out there to read if you do a web search. A full explanation here is outside the scope of the answer, since this is already a somewhat common task with many potential solutions.

Comment: I would appreciate some documentation to prevent initialization and initialize it manually. I have not found any official documentation that talks about this. Is this really a common task? Not found any post with a solution or even documentation.

Comment: It's been written about a lot, and you can find the articles by doing a web search.

Comment: I have not found official documentation with "Prevent firebase initialization" keywords. I don't understand why there is no API if it is a common task.

Comment: Try using the most relevant words I provided in my comment: "android manually initialize firebase"

Comment: Thanks, I have found an article writteng by you: "How does Firebase initialize on Android?" I think the answer could be there, I am reading it. Let's see if I come to the solution :)

Comment: Hi, I have been some hours and I think it is working. I have updated the question to let you see what I have done. I have followed your "Take Control of Your Firebase Init on Android". What I don't really understand is why the part of the builder to initialize Firebase is not working for me at first, but if I also add .setProjectId(MyProjectName) it is working. Maybe now it is requiered to setProjectId as the Article is from 2017 ?

Comment: Hi, I have seen that you have edited and deleted my update of the question. Did you do that because the implementation I did is wrong? Please could you clarify my questions in last message? I really need your help and I would appreciate all your help. Thanks

Comment: You changed the question, which is not good on Stack Overflow when there is already an answer that addresses the original question.  If your original question gets an answer that addresses it as originally stated, that should be left alone as a record for others in the future.  You had a followup question which covered the specific details of your code, which is right.  Followup or additional questions need their own post in order to be compliant with Stack Overflow guidelines.

Comment: Okay I'm really sorry, I am new in this forum and now I have learnt from the mistake. I only wanted you to see what I have done to correct me if I made a mistake in my code. Please could you explain me why it was not working for me until I put .setProjectId(my_project_id). Do you think it is good as I did? Thank you so much

Comment: That would be a topic for another question.  Please create a new post and share what is not working the way you expect with the code you have.

Comment: Okay, I have created a new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76427285/manually-firebase-initialization-only-working-when-using-setprojectid

Answer (score 0):

**Update apparently working:**

I have followed "Take Control of Your Firebase Init on Android" article:
https://firebase.blog/posts/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on/
What I have done:

I have added to my root **AndroidManifest.xml** the following to disable automatic Provider merger as explained in the article:

```
    <application
<provider
    android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider"
    tools:node="remove"
    />
    </application>
```

After this I have manually initialized Firebase:

In OnCreate() method:

```
FirebaseOptions.Builder builder = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setApplicationId("1:0123456789012:android:0123456789abcdef")
    .setApiKey("your_api_key")
    .setStorageBucket("your-app.appspot.com");
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, builder.build());
```

Note: I have not used.setDatabaseUrl("https://your-app.firebaseio.com") as I not use Database Service.

Okay, this was not working form me (services were not working due that the provider isn't merging now (this is totally expected), but initialization was not working and I din't know why)

What I have done to make it work and don't know why adding the following is working:

I have added `.setProjectId` to the builder and now is working as expected.