# Manually Firebase initialization only working when using .setProjectId()

Tags: android, firebase

I have been trying to manually initialize Firebase.

I have followed "Take Control of Your Firebase Init on Android" article: https://firebase.blog/posts/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on/

What I have done:

I have added to my root AndroidManifest.xml the following to disable automatic Provider merger as explained in the article:

```
    <application
<provider
    android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider"
    tools:node="remove"
    />
    </application>
```

After this I have manually initialized Firebase:

In OnCreate() method:

```
FirebaseOptions.Builder builder = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setApplicationId("1:0123456789012:android:0123456789abcdef")
    .setApiKey("your_api_key")
    .setStorageBucket("your-app.appspot.com");
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, builder.build());
```

Note: I have not used .setDatabaseUrl("https://your-app.firebaseio.com") as I don't use Database Service (I don't really know if I can omit this.

Okay, this was not working form me (services were not working due that the provider isn't merging now (this is totally expected), but initialization was not working and I din't know why)

What I have done to make it work and don't know why adding the following is working:

I have added .setProjectId(my_project_id) to the builder and now is working as expected:

```
FirebaseOptions.Builder builder = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setApplicationId("1:0123456789012:android:0123456789abcdef")
    .setApiKey("your_api_key")
    .setStorageBucket("your-app.appspot.com")
    .setProjectId(my_project_id);
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, builder.build());
```

Now I have the following question:

Why it is only working if I add .setProjectId(my_project_id) to the builder if in the guide that method is not used? Could it be that as the guide was written in 2017 this manually implementation has changed a little bit or maybe it is because the implementation I did is worng?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what Firebase products you use. The Firebase Realtime Database for example, only needs the database URL to be specified, while most other back-end services need at least the project ID and possibly some other values.

I find it best to specify all configuration values in my code, to prevent bumping into such problems later on as I start using more services.

Comment: "I find it best to specify all configuration values in my code" -- Okay, but for example, if I have not configured Firebase Realtime Database in my firebase project, it is not possible for me to use setDatabaseUrl("https://your-app.firebaseio.com") and it is totally fine not using it, right? I mean, what I should specify is all configuration that it is possible for me to determine using the products I am using, right?

Comment: Correct. So if you didn't initialize a specific service you won't specify that value - and it won't be a problem as you're not using it.

Comment: Hello again, one last question, I have been trying to .setGaTrackingId() but I have not found that GaTrackingId. I have seen that this is because that is used for Google Analytics but not used for Firebase Analytics. To end up, I have been able to complete all setters except .setDatabaseUrl() and .setGaTrackingId(). Do you think that if I am only using firebase crashlytics and firebase analytics services, they will work with the setters I have put?

Comment: well I have noticed that crashlytics is working correctly, but analytics not working...

Comment: `setDatabaseUrl` is only used by the realtime database. Given its name it sounds like `setGaTrackingId` is indeed needed for analytics. I haven't needed that myself, but this seem promising: https://www.google.com/search?q=where+to+find+the+google+analytics+tracking+ID

Comment: okay, thanks, at least I know that analytics is not working because I need setGaTrackingId. My problem is that it seems that Firebase is generating that tracking id for analytics automatically and I am not able to get that tracking id, I created this new post to see if someone know how could I get it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76432434/i-cant-find-gatrackingid-in-my-firebase-project