# I can't find GaTrackingId in my Firebase project

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

I am trying to find GaTrackingId to set it in the builder using `builder.setGaTrackingId()` but I can't find this tracking id.

I have followed this guide:  https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9539598?hl=en

These are the steps of this guide:

1-Click Admin in your Universal Analytics property.

2-In the Property column, click Property Settings.

3-Your "UA-" ID appears at the top of the Property Settings page.

But in the last step, I can only see Property Name, Sector Category, Time Zone and Currency displayed as. I don't see any Tracking Id.